# java permission error on first run of newly installed Neo4J server

Tags: java, linux, neo4j

I'm setting up a new server for an application (node.js with Neo4j 1.8.3) that hasn't been used for a while.  I installed Oracle JDK 7 (latest), which might explain this issue, as it's not recommended
for 1.8.3, will retest with JDK 6 tomorrow.

I installed Neo4J 1.8.3 on Thursday, on Ubuntu 14.04 running on Linode.  Today I reviewed the log file (neo4j.0.0.log) and saw the following error:

```
Oct 02, 2014 5:02:48 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
WARNING: Couldn't create user preferences directory. User preferences are unusable.
```

After that there are numerous errors as follows:

```
WARNING: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
Oct 02, 2014 12:00:46 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences checkLockFile0ErrorCode
```

This discussion seems relevant,

[java system preferences under different users in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960451/java-system-preferences-under-different-users-in-linux)

But before trying this I wanted to ask here. Is this a known problem with a standard solution?

Comment: can you check the read/write/owner privileges on the database directory?  Are you using a different user now?  If not interested in using sudo, try changing the directory permissions to allow the user ID you're using now

Comment: The data directory and all subdirectories have owner neo4j (that is the user neo4j is running as) and nogroup as group. The owner has r/w/x privileges on data directory and all subdirectories. I had thought this error referred to the user's home directory.  The Neo4j directory itself was set with me as the owner, to be on the safe side will change all to be owned by neo4j.  I just noticed that neo4j user doesn't have a home directory, which may explain this problem, I will create one.

Comment: I see now that neo4j's default home directory is /var/lib/neo4j.  The user neo4j is owner and has r/w/x permissions on that directory.

Comment: just to be sure - I'm assuming you have restarted the process and perhaps even the VM - I wonder if there is a file lock which is causing the issue and perhaps might need to be removed

Comment: I always shut down neo4j before making any changes.  Once I made sure that /var/lib/neo4j and also /home/neo4j existed, I restarted neo4j and the error seems to be fixed.  I will keep in mind for the future of the possible need to restart VM in this kind of situation.  Thanks for your help.